# How to turn on CGI/FastCGI on Zend Server for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: joomla, cgi, fastcgi, zend-server, ubuntu-server

When using Zend Server on the Windows, CMS systems like Joomla runs OK but when I'm installed default Zend Server CE on my live Ubuntu Server - I have problems with file permissions probably because CGI/FastCGI is not running. **How to turn on CGI/FastCGI for Zend Server on Ubuntu**/Debian so server will be more compatible with CMS systems? 
In my PHP info for windows lines appear:
Server API: CGI/FastCGI

PHP info on Ubuntu Server
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
PHP Version 5.3.14
Zend Server Community Edition 5.6.0
Server Software Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Zend Framework 1.12.0

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You might find that informative:
[enable FastCGI for a certain virtualhost](http://www.mwop.net/blog/243-Running-mod_php-and-FastCGI-side-by-side.html)